# Backing up all Visual Force pages with Eclipse and Force.com

Tags: visualforce, eclipse

How could be possible to backup all the Visual Force pages using Force.com Eclipse?

Comment: Usually, I zip the whole project code.                                                         Steps: File > Export.
Select the General > Archive File export wizard.
Select the project(s) to be exported.
Choose the archive file type (ZIP or TAR), and other options.
Enter the archive file name.
Click Finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticate to your org with the Force.com IDE (using your SFDC username/password + security token if applicable), make sure "Visualforce Pages" are included in your local project (I haven't used Eclipse in some time, unsure if VF pages are subscribed by default), create project -> the files for the pages (and other metadata types you specified during setup) will be in your local project directory on your machine.

As an aside, I suggest you check out Mavensmate for Sublime or Welkin Suite, I think you may prefer both over Eclipse.

Comment: So, by using the "Choose Metadata Components -> Pages" am I going to download all the salesforce pages? Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Using eclipse you can take backup of metadata by creating a project as mentioned in previous answers. But each time when you need to take backup, you have to refresh metadata from server and back it up manually.

Follow the steps below for backup your developed application.

1. Create new project and select Force.com
2. Enter username, password,security Token
3. Select Environment in which you have to take backup e.g Sandbox.

Now Select options which way you have to use for download your data. After that show the list of folder in which you have to find your folder Like Object,Trigger,Classes, Pages etc. Click on each component to fetch data from server into Eclipse.

Note:
If you want to backup meta data then create a new project using eclipse and then use a version control system like git or svn to back it up.

You cannot backup data using eclipse.